# Video files thumbnails not showing

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, thumbnails

I have already tried all of the different solutions which I found online, even messing with the Registry, but nothing has worked so far. What could be another possibility to fix this issue?

If it makes a difference, I have VLC em K-Lite Codec Pack installed.

Comment: Try the [Shark007 codec pack](http://shark007.net/win7codecs.html) instead.

Comment: It worked, post as an answer.

Comment: It did work, but someone else tried getting the credit for it.

Comment: Yes, I will mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my own experience I have found [Shark007's codec pack](http://shark007.net/win7codecs.html) to be much more stable than K-Lite's offering. Try that instead.

Answer (score -1):

This program "Media Preview" seems to solve the problem. Get it here - http://www.babelsoft.net/products.htm

Comment: Please explain why this program would solve the issue.

Comment: That site seems to jump around between Chinese and English, and also looks fairly sketchy. Please explain how to use the program to solve the problem.